# Can a method return an NSRange?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

I have a method that returns an NSRange. When I call this method from outside the class I get a compile error.

```
NSRange tmpRange;
tmpRange = [phrase rangeInString:searchString forString:theLetter goingForward:YES];
return tmpRange.location == -1;
```

in the .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Phrase : NSObject {

}
- (NSRange) rangeInString:(NSString *) tgt forString:(NSString *) find goingForward:(BOOL) fwd;  

@end
```

This method is called within the Phrase object by other methods without problems. The compiler says 'incompatible types in assignment'.

Can anyone explain this to me? I assume it has to do with returning an NSRange/struct type value generated outside the object, but I don't know why it works in one place and not the other.

Comment: Note that typically you should use `NSNotFound` as the `location` field value for an invalid `NSRange`.

Comment: Hmm -- for a variety of low-quality reasons, I'm in effect using the location value as a kind of error code: -1 is one such code. All the codes are less than zero. This can't really have anything to do with the error, since the compiler doesn't know what will be returned at runtime. But that's why I'm not using NSNotFound...

Comment: The location variable is defined as an NSUInteger, so it will never be less than zero. You're supposed to use NSNotFound.

Comment: But that's entirely irrelevant to why an error should be thrown at compile time for an assignment that simply dumps the result of a methdo: a method that works fine inside the class it is defined in. It can't know what the values returned will be.

Answer (score 5):

Of course a method can return NSRange. But returning structures require special attention to the compiler because how the method is invoked is usually different (`objc_msgSend_stret` vs. `objc_msgSend`).

Please make sure you declare `phrase` as

```
Phrase* phrase = ...;
```

so that the compiler knows `-rangeInString:…` is returning an NSRange, instead of

```
id phrase = ...;
```

(Also, since you don't show which line the compiler errors, make sure the function using `return … == -1;` is returning a BOOL not NSRange.)

Comment: You also need to make certain that the header file containing the Phrase interface is imported into the file that invokes the method.

Comment: Phrase is imported -- see my comment below. The instance of Phrase is already declared, and multiple references are made to the Phrase instance elsewhere in the same class, in other methods.

The line that throws the error is the one that assigns tmpRange to the result of the method call.

Comment: @Dan: How do you declare the **variable** `phrase`?

Answer (score 2):

> Can a method return an NSRange?

Yes.

> This method is called within the Phrase object by other methods without problems. … When I call this method from outside the class I get a compile error. … The compiler says 'incompatible types in assignment'.

Remember to `#import` Phrase.h into the implementation file where you're talking to a Phrase object. Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know about your `rangeOfString:forString:goingForward:` method and *assumes* that it returns `id`. It needs the `@interface` in the header file to *know* that the method returns `NSRange`.

Assuming that your phrase object is in an instance variable, you probably declared the Phrase class with `@class Phrase;` in the header file where you declared the ivar. That's a forward declaration; it tells the compiler that a class named “Phrase” exists (so that a declaration like `Phrase *myPhrase` will be legal), but it doesn't tell the compiler anything else about it. To do that, you need to import the header.

The general rule, for instances of class A knowing about instances of class B, is for A's header (A.h) to forward-declare class B with `@class`, and A's implementation (A.m) to import B's header (B.h).

A different case is when A is a subclass of B. You need the `@interface` to make a subclass, so in this case and this case only, A.h must import B.h. Since it's importing the header for B, it does not need to forward-declare B.

Comment: Actually, the Phrase class is imported, not declared with @class. The non-Phrase class imports Phrase, and Phrase does not import the other class (just Foundation). Phrase declares that the return value is an NSRange. The class calling the Phrase-class method stores an instance of Phrase, called phrase inside itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the answer, but NSRange.location is declared as NSUInteger.  By comparing it to -1, you are comparing an unsigned value to a signed value.

The only other answer I can think of is that the .m file you are making the call from has not imported the header Phrase.h.  Now, I know you believe it has, but the compiler is saying otherwise.  Try running the preprocessor on the file to see what it is actually importing. (right click in an editor containing the .m file - preprocess is near the bottom of the context menu that pops up).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return C structs in methods. That is not the problem. Also, location is an NSUInteger and will never be -1. Use NSNotFound to test for that.

How is the instance of your Phrase object typed? Did you use `id` instead of `Phrase *`? Have you properly imported the Phrase header?

You should give us more information about the code that's giving the compile error.

Answer (score 1):

In response to some questions that are coming up:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OverlayView.h"
#import "Phrase.h"
#import "TimerPaneView.h"
```

Is the header in the MainPane.h, the class header for where the call is being made.

In the header for MainPane.h, phrase is declared:

```
    Phrase              *phrase;
```

And in the implementation file, which, yes, imports the MainPane header:

```
phrase = [[Phrase alloc] init];
```

Is how the phrase class is being instantiated, in the initWithFrame method. I refer to the phrase object dozens and dozens of times, calling methods, referring to properties in this class, without problems. And no, the phrase object is never released until dealloc.

-- added: I thought I had found the problem: a collapsed section of code that never is called that had a legacy return value that was BOOL. This method originally returned BOOL, but was converted. But I eliminated it, and the problem remains.

I should also say that I've refactored my way around this problem, but it remains a mystery...